# Are there any pbta systems with built in downtime systems?

Tags: downtime, powered-by-the-apocalypse, blades-in-the-dark, monster-of-the-week

I'm about to start running a Monster of the Week campaign and I wanted to have a downtime system for between adventures to give the players an opportunity to do extra stuff on the side and get a narrative peak at the "domestic" life of the characters. I was planning on trying to hack in something similar to the Blades in the Dark downtime system, but I didn't know if there were any pbta systems that already had one I could check out, or if anyone had done something similar and had advice. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. [I fear this might be closed as a shopping question because it mainly looks for recommendations rather than advice](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5747/8610); that is, the site shies away from just providing a list of games. Consider rephrasing the question to something like *How can I incorporate downtime into* Monster of the Week? or *Will using the downtime system from* Blades in the Dark *unbalance my* Monster of the Week *campaign?* Both of these are questions the site can answer. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: You might look at "start of session" moves from AW (but many PbtA have them as well). This is about as close to a downtime mechanic as I've seen.